# Injective dimension of $\mathbb Z_n$ as a $\mathbb Z$-module

Tags: commutative-algebra, homological-algebra, injective-module

> What is the injective dimension of $\mathbb Z_n$ as a $\mathbb Z$-module?

Can one use the well-known fact that $id(M)$ is less than or equal to $i$ iff $Ext^{i+1}(N,M)=0$ for all $N$? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the following exact sequence $0\to\mathbb Z\stackrel{n\cdot}\to\mathbb Z\to\mathbb Z/n\mathbb Z\to 0$ we get $\operatorname{Ext}^2(N,\mathbb Z/n\mathbb Z)=0$ for all $N$, so the injective dimension of $\mathbb Z/n\mathbb Z$ as $\mathbb Z$-module is at most $1$. However, it is not injective since it isn't divisible, so its injective dimension must be $1$.

(I have used that the injective dimension of $\mathbb Z$ as $\mathbb Z$-module is $1$, and this follows easily from the short exact sequence $0\to\mathbb Z\to\mathbb Q\to\mathbb Q/\mathbb Z\to 0$.)

Answer (score 5):

If you look at the [wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Injective_module#First_examples), $\mathbb Q/\mathbb Z$ is injective. The obvious map $\mathbb Z_n\to\mathbb Q/\mathbb Z$ is an injection, and the quotient of this inclusion is isomorphic to $\mathbb Q/\mathbb Z$, so you have an injective resolution:

$$0\rightarrow\mathbb Z_n\rightarrow \mathbb Q/\mathbb Z\rightarrow \mathbb Q/\mathbb Z\to 0$$

So all you have to do is prove that the $\mathbb Z_n$ is not itself injective to get the dimension is $1$.

Comment: You get dimension 1 ;)

Comment: Ah, yes, injective dimensions start at zero. Will fix.

Comment: @Andrews:Why the quotient is isomorphic to $\mathbb Q/\mathbb Z$?

Comment: Ah, I didn't want to give you the complete answer, @karparvar. :)

Comment: @Andrews: By $\mathbb Z_n$ I mean $\mathbb Z/n\mathbb Z$. So each element of $\mathbb Z_n$ goes to zero in $\mathbb Q/\mathbb Z$!

Comment: No, $1$ in $\mathbb Z/n\mathbb Z$ goes to $\frac{1}{n}+\mathbb Z$ in $\mathbb Q/\mathbb Z$. At least, that was the "obvious" inclusion I meant... @karparvar

Comment: Actually you identify $\mathbb Z_n$ with the cyclic subgroup generated by (the residue class) of $\frac 1n$ in $\mathbb Q/\mathbb Z$. It remains to prove that $\mathbb Q/\mathbb Z$ over this subgroup is isomorphic to $\mathbb Q/\mathbb Z$.

Comment: Yes, as I said in the comment in comments above, I left that for the reader. It seems fairly obvious to me, but it definitely requires proof. @user26857

Answer (score 1):

In $\textrm{Mod-}\mathbb{Z}$, a module is injective if and only if it is divisible. If a module $M$ is not divisible, embed it into its injective envelope $E(M)$. Then the exact sequence
$$
0\to M\to E(M)\to E(M)/M\to0
$$
shows that the injective dimension of $M$ is at most $1$, because $E(M)/M$ is divisible, hence injective.

This can be generalized to (right) hereditary rings, that is, rings in which quotients of injective right modules are injective.

*Exercise.* A ring is right hereditary if and only if submodules of projective modules are projective.